# Escaping SQL queries in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a program that runs queries on a sqlite db and I want to replace any ' character in my query with ''.

The code I am using:

val.Value.Replace(',' '\'\ ')

But my vs doesnt accept that, is there a different method?

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably need [DbParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not escaping strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below uses quotes (") to encapsulate the two parameters of the Replace statement.  In this case, the first parameter is a single quote (') and the second is two single quotes ('').  This result in the code below.

```
val.Replace("'","''")
```

Comment: Hi @user2757455 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi eventually i did something else very similiar to your solution, also i cant find where to mark the currect answer (using firefox)

Comment: Just underneath the up arrow beside the answer, you should see a greyed check mark. Click the check mark and it will turn green.  Here is an image of what it looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png.

Answer (score 0):

```
string val = "' ' d '";
val = val.Replace("'", "\"");
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

I just show how to do it with a test string. Instead of using ', use ".